# JavaScript function is working fine with alert and not without it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery datepicker in repeater control.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" onclick=showcalender(<%#Container.ItemIndex %>) value='<%# Container.DataItem("BIRTH_DATE") %>' />
```

I have defined JavaScript function as:

```
function showcalender(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById('datepicker' + id);
  $(e).datepicker();
  //alert(id);
}
```

This date control popup opens when I use alert. But without it, its working intermittently,

Comment: Show us the whole code

Comment: "its working intermittently" - we don't know what this means

Comment: The JavaScript function work fine with alert in it. Without alert it works sometimes only.

Comment: "works sometimes only" - still not good

Comment: Works with alert/doesn't work without alert usually means the delay caused by displaying the alert is allowing some script file to complete loading.  I would say you have executed this function without all the scripts being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited visibility to you code here I can only suggest a change - If you're just using the click handlers to instantiate the date pickers, its best to add a class (say, myClass for example) to them and instantiate them like this instead.

```
$(document).on('focus',".myClass", function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker') === false )  {
        $(this).datepicker();
    }
});​
```

Comment: While your suggestion may be helpful to OP, this is not an answer (as you yourself have acnkowledged). I realize OP hasn't posted enough information, but this should likely be a comment instead of an answer.